# заблокировали на stackoverflow

Tags: поддержка, запрет-публикаций

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, получила такое сообщение при попытке задать вопрос, не понимаю как это исправить и вообще за что забанили, почти все вопросы были по теме написания кода, исправлять нечего, как вариант выхода из ситуации вижу только создание нового аккаунта, есть ли ещё варианты как убрать блокировку?

Comment: Блокировка автоматическая и накладывается или снимается только голосами пользователей. Я проголосовал за пару ваших вопросов, блокировка снялась. Следите за качеством вопросов, и подобная ситуация не повторится. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Так сама ж вчера пачку вопросов удалила...

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так они уже очень давно без ответа, да и не нужны, вот подумала, что если их убрать, то что-то лучше станет

Comment: @aepot, спасибо

Comment: @Елизавета, насколько я помню формулу - наоборот хуже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, O_O А вы знаете разве эту формулу?

Comment: @Глеб, она где-то была по ссылкам в дубликате.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, буду знать

Comment: Я получила ответ на это вопрос, теперь нужно как-то его закрыть или пометить что он с ответом?

Comment: Нет, делать ничего не надо. Ответа в формальном смысле слова на него нету и принять его, соответственно, нельзя. Тем более, это дубликат.